# Deserialize string list as List

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson

I have an object like this:

```java
class Test {
    List<Integer> a;
}
```

I want both the following JSON to be parsed correctly:

```json
{ "a" : "[1, 2, 3]" }
{ "a" : [1, 2, 3] }
```

When I try to deserialize it in Jackson with the data type as follows, it throws the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
> deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Integer>`
> from String value (token `JsonToken.VALUE_STRING`)

How can I create a custom deserializer for this case? I've already tried creating one like the following, and it doesn't work and wasn't called during deserialization, probably because of generic type erasure.

```kotlin
val jackson = ObjectMapper().apply {
    registerModule(SimpleModule().addDeserializer(ArrayList::class.java, object : JsonDeserializer<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext) =
            parser.text.trim('[', ']').split(',').map { it.toInt() } as ArrayList<Integer>
    }))
}
```

Comment: One is String, the other is a List. What you are asking, is that even possible?

Comment: how about first parsing it as a regular string, then passing the string as a json string to the parser a second time?

Comment: @BIBOOnation, that won't work either. The OP's second example mentions `[1, 2, 3]`, no String literals.

Comment: Yeah, I was referring to the string version, but it seems you did the same thing I was thinking of

Comment: I have added another way of doing so. @BIBOOnation, your opinion on the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. If you are ready to use a `JsonNode`, this is possible. Although this code does not involve your `Test` class, maybe you can work on it yourself.
Try below mentioned code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String enteredJson = "{ \"a\" : \"[1, 2, 3]\" }";
//        String json1 = "{ \"a\" : [1, 2, 3] }";

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            JsonNode jsonNode1 = objectMapper.readTree(enteredJson);

            List<Integer> list1;
             if (jsonNode1.has("a")) {
                if (jsonNode1.get("a").isTextual()) {
                    String innerJson1 = jsonNode1.get("a").asText();
                    list1 = objectMapper.readValue(innerJson1, new ArrayList<>().getClass());
                    System.out.println("List from String: " + list1);
                } else if (jsonNode1.get("a").isArray()) {
                    list1 = objectMapper.readValue(jsonNode1.get("a").traverse(), new ArrayList<>().getClass());
                    System.out.println("List from List: " + list1);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

You can comment/uncomment the `enteredJson` and check.

**EDIT**

Here is another solution that involves your `Test` class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author asgar
 */
public class Test {

    List<Integer> a;

    public List<Integer> getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(Object a) {
        try {
            List<Integer> list1 = null;
            if (a instanceof String) {
                String bracketsRemoved = a.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(bracketsRemoved.split(", ")));
                list1 = list.stream().map(e -> Integer.parseInt(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            } else if (a instanceof ArrayList) {
                list1 = (List) a;
            }
            this.a = list1;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.a = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And your main class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 *
 * @author asgar
 */
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String value = "{ \"a\" : \"[1, 2, 3]\" }";
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            Test test = mapper.readValue(value, Test.class);
            System.out.println("MY LIST " + test.a);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException pre) {
            pre.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

For this solution I have passed `Object` into the `set` method, you can figure out the rest.

Comment: Isn't that just a workaround, a dirty hack around an error in the input data? In the first sample, the value of 'a' is a String with a weird content, while in the second sample it is a List of Integer. Of course, with some additional knowledge about that "weird content" of the String, one can parse it to a List of Integer, too. But what about the JSON `{ "a" : "1" }` – is it valid? Or not? And why?

Comment: Yes @tquadrat, that is a workaround. There are several cases where the solution won’t work. But as far as I understand the OP says either it is a list of integer or a list of integer provided as string

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide a solution with a different approach using the class `StdDeserializer`, as I think it would centralize better the unmarshalling logic in a single point, making it more compact, flexible and readable.

Firstly, we need to separate the two cases:

##### Elements as an array

1. Create an `Iterable` from an `Iterator` of the node's elements.
2. Use the `StreamSupport` class and the `Iterable.spliterator()` method to stream the elements.
3. Map each element to an `Integer`.
4. Collect all elements into a `List<Integer>`.

##### Elements as a String

1. Retrieve the array as a String with `rootNode.get("a").asText()`.
2. Remove the square brackets with a regex.
3. Split the elements with a comma.
4. Create a generic `Stream<T>` with the elements.
5. Map each element to an `Integer` (and previously removing any white space).
6. Collect all elements into a `List<Integer>`.

## Implementation

##### MyDeserializer.java

```
public class MyDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Test> {
    public MyDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MyDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Test deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JacksonException {
        JsonNode rootNode = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

        if (rootNode.get("a").isArray()) {
            //1. Creating an Iterable from an Iterator of the node's elements
            Iterable<JsonNode> iterable = () -> rootNode.get("a").elements();

            //2. Using the StreamSupport class and Iterable.spliterator method to stream the elements
            //3. Mapping each element to an int and automatically boxing them to Integer as we have a generic Stream<T> and not an IntStream
            //4. Collecting all elements into a List<Integer>
            return new Test(StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).map(node -> node.asInt()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        if (rootNode.get("a").isTextual()) {
            //1. Retrieving the array as a String with rootNode.get("a").asText()
            //2. Removing the square brackets with a regex
            //3. Splitting the elements with a comma
            String[] elements = rootNode.get("a").asText().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");

            //4. Creating a generic Stream<T> with the elements
            //5. Mapping each element to an Integer (and previously removing any white space)
            //6. Collecting all elements into a List<Integer>
            return new Test(Arrays.stream(elements).map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.trim())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

##### Test.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonDeserialize(using = MyDeserializer.class)
public class Test {
    List<Integer> a;
}
```

## Live Demo

Here is also a live demo at [oneCompiler.com](https://onecompiler.com/java/427tntxcg)